# How to pass login using selenium with multiple classes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to pass a username and password to a login page which has a multiple class structure.

I have tried various XPATH solutions but have been unable to make one work for this example. Here is the sites HTML code. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<div class="hm-HeaderModule_UserAdmin ">
<div class="hm-Login ">

<div class="hm-Login_UserNameWrapper ">
<input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
<div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Join Now</div></div>

<div class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ">
<input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
<input type="password" class="hm-Login_InputField Hidden ">
<button tabindex="0" class="hm-Login_LoginBtn ">GO</button>
<div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Lost Login?</div></div></div></div>
```

Both of the text fields for the Username and Password input are located by hm-Login_InputField

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try use `CSS Selector` which is much faster.Use `WebdriverWait` to handle the element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url here")

wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
userele=wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper input.hm-Login_InputField[type="text"]')))
userele.send_keys('xyz@gmail.com')
passwdele=wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper input.hm-Login_InputField.Hidden[type="password"]')))
passwdele.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxxx')
btnelement=wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper button.hm-Login_LoginBtn')))

btnelement.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wasn't able to get this to work exactly for the example but can understand the premise and will have another attempt, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however the password field does not receive the send_keys command due to the the wrapper containing the text and hidden password field of the same box. I have tried clicking the password box first and then sending keys to the hidden element however still nothing is appearing. Do you have any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check below XPath's using following-sibling

```
Username (XPath) - //div[@class='class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper']/following-sibling::input[1]
Password (XPath) - //div[@class='class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper']/following-sibling::input[2]
```

Note - Kindly checkout space at last of wrapper`<div class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ">`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , check if the Username and the Password fields are inside a Frame if they are inside an IFrame switch to it and then execute , it happened to me once as i missed the frames part so hope it helps for you :)